# Ruby: How to decode strings which are partially encoded or fully encoded?

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, decode, string-decoding

I am getting encoded strings while parsing text files. I have no idea on how to decode them to english or it's original language.

```
  "inf&#111;&#64;c&#108;&#111;ud&#97;g&#46;&#99;&#111;m"
```

is the encoded string and needs to have it decoded.

I want to decode using Ruby.

Here is a [link](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/) for your reference and I am expecting the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like HTML encoding, not URL encoding.

```
require 'cgi'

CGI.unescapeHTML("inf&#111;&#64;c&#108;&#111;ud&#97;g&#46;&#99;&#111;m")
#=> "info@cloudag.com"
```